# Implement ParallaxBackground extended from Actor with libgdx

Tags: java, android-studio, background, libgdx

ParallaxBackground.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;

public class ParallaxBackground extends Actor{

    private List<ParallaxLayer> layers;
    private float width, height;

    public ParallaxBackground(float width, float height) {
        this.layers = new ArrayList<ParallaxLayer>();
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void render(float xPosition, float yPosition, SpriteBatch batch) {
        for (ParallaxLayer layer : layers) {
            float layerOffsetX = (xPosition * layer.getxRatio() % width);
            float layerOffsetY = (yPosition * layer.getyRatio() % height);
            layer.render(xPosition - width / 2f - layerOffsetX, yPosition - height / 2f - layerOffsetY, width, height, batch);
            layer.render(xPosition - width / 2f - layerOffsetX + 5f, yPosition - height / 2f - layerOffsetY, width, height, batch);
        }
    }

    public List<ParallaxLayer> getLayers() {
        return layers;
    }

    public float getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public float getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void addLayer(ParallaxLayer parallaxLayer) {
        layers.add(parallaxLayer);
    }

}
```

ParallaxLayer .java

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;

public class ParallaxLayer {

    private TextureRegion region;
    private float xRatio, yRatio;

    public ParallaxLayer(TextureRegion region, float xRatio, float yRatio) {
        super();
        this.region = region;
        this.xRatio = xRatio;
        this.yRatio = yRatio;
    }

    public TextureRegion getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public float getxRatio() {
        return xRatio;
    }

    public float getyRatio() {
        return yRatio;
    }

    public void render(float xPosition, float yPosition, float width, float height, SpriteBatch batch) {
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(region, xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
        batch.end();
    }

}
```

and my class game i have add this on the create() method:

```
ParallaxBackground bg = new ParallaxBackground(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
bg.addLayer(new ParallaxLayer(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.jpg"))),0,0));
stage.addActor(bg);
```

my goal is to slide horizontally the background in an infinite loop.
Now , the only problem is , I can not see the background , that is not me you see , I'm wrong implementation by chance ?
Can anyone tell me how to correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your ParallaxBackground's render method is being called?

Actor does not define a render() method. Instead, the stage calls

```
draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha)
```

on each actor it contains. My guess is that you need to implement "draw" in your ParallaxBackground class.

Also, make sure that you are calling

```
stage.draw();
```

somewhere in your main rendering loop